# Git is not using the first editor in my $PATH

Tags: macos, git, path, editor, homebrew

I am using OS X 10.8, and I used brew to install a more recent version of emacs than the one shipped with OS X.

The newer emacs binary is installed in `/usr/local/bin` (24.2.1), and the old "shipped-with-osx" one in `/usr/bin` (22.1.1).

I updated my `$PATH` env variable by prepending `/usr/local/bin` to it. It works fine in my shell (ie. typing `emacs` runs the 24.2.1 version), but when git opens the editor, the emacs version is 22.1.1.

Isn't git supposed to use `$PATH` to find the editor I want to use ?

Additional informations:

```
$ type -a emacs
emacs is /usr/local/bin/emacs
emacs is /usr/bin/emacs
emacs is /usr/local/bin/emacs
$ env
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
SHELL=/bin/zsh
PAGER=most
EDITOR=emacs -nw
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Please note that I'd prefer not to set the absolute path of my editor directly in my git conf, as I use this conf across multiple systems.

**EDIT**: Here's an bit of my `.zshrc`:

```
# Mac OS X
if [ `uname` = "Darwin" ]; then
    # Brew binaries
    PATH="/usr/local/bin":"/usr/local/sbin":$PATH
else # Everyone else (Linux)
    # snip
fi
```

So, yes, I could add a line `export EDITOR='/usr/local/bin emacs -nw'` in the first `if`, but I'd like to understand why `git` is not using my `PATH` variable :)

Comment: Yes, it should pick up the editor from the path.  Where did you put this adjustment to your `PATH`?  `.zshrc`?  Maybe it needs to go in `.zshenv`.  IIRC, `.zshrc` is only sourced in an interactive shell.

Comment: What's the arguments and working path when git opens the editor? Maybe you should check your repository config file.

Comment: Putting the `PATH` adjustment in `.zshenv` did not fix the problem, and emacs 22.1.1 is always used whatever command I use or the repo I am in (and I checked my per-repo configs, no trace of editor related configuration there).

Comment: Why are there two emacs in /usr/local/bin/emacs? Maybe it looks in /usr/local/bin, but takes the old instead of new one there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing `git 1.8.0` fixed the issue.

Old version was `1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1)`. This is weird as I didn't find any references to this kind of problem in the changelogs.

Comment: This appears to be a difference between the version of git that apple ships with xcode and the standard version, not a difference between 1.7.9 and 1.8.  My /usr/bin/git is "git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)" and it uses the incorrect path as well.  A separate installation of git (1.8.4. from macports) works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to set the full path in the environment variable.

OSX uses bash(1) by default, so stick `export EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/emacs -nw` somewhere in your `.bash_profile` to set the variable for all interactive bash shells.

Comment: Setting the `EDITOR` env variable to the full path works, but as I mentioned in my question, I'd prefer not to use this solution as my confs files are used across multiple systems. Setting this in .bash_profile does not works, I used `chsh` to set `zsh` as my default shell.