# How do I configure git to inherit my specific $PATH environment variable?

Tags: macos, git, bash, emacs

My goal is to have a set of dot files shared between the many shell accounts I have so that I can have a similar environment in each one. Because of that, I don't want machine/environment specific information in my .git files or my .bash files.

On my MacOSX machine, the default emacs version is 22. I have installed a newer version of emacs (24) in `/usr/local/bin`. In my .bashrc file I set my default editor to emacs: `export EDITOR=emacs`. Before this, I also set up my path so that `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/usr/bin` so that the newer version of emacs gets selected.

When I use git to create commit messages, it always picks the one in `/usr/bin` instead of the one in `/usr/local/bin`. Git is ignoring my `$PATH` settings. I used to hardcode the location of the version of emacs I wanted in my .gitconfigure file, but that won't work when I use that same .gitconfigure file on my Ubuntu server. (If it's unclear, what I'm saying is that modifying my .gitconfigure editor option to point to a hardcoded won't work for me).

**Why doesn't git respect my `$PATH` settings?**

**How do I configure git to use the correct emacs?**

---

*Edit: Adding more context*

There is a suggestion to put environment variables in `.profile/.bash_profile`. Here's some relevant code from my `.bashrc` and my `.bash_profile`

**`.bashrc`**

*Note: I wrote a bash function called `vercomp` which compares version numbers.*

```
OS=''                                                                                                
case $OSTYPE in                                                                                      
  darwin*)  OS='Mac' ;;                                                                              
  linux*)   OS='Linux'  ;;                                                                           
  *)        OS='UNKNOWN' ;;                                                                          
esac                                                                                                 

export EDITOR=emacs 

if [[ $OS = 'Mac' ]]; then                                                                           
    ### EMACS VERSION CHECK                                                                          
    # make sure that we're working with emacs >= 24                                                  
    wanted_ver=24                                                                                    
    curr_ver=`emacs --version | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]+\.[.[:digit:]]*'`                              
    vercomp $curr_ver $wanted_ver                                                                    

    # If vercomp returns 2, then our current emacs version isn't good enough.                        
    if [[ $? == 2 ]]; then                                                                           
        if [[ -e '/usr/local/bin/emacs' ]]; then                                                     
            emacs_path='/usr/local/bin/emacs -nw'                                                    
        elif  [[ -e '/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs' ]]; then                          
            emacs_path='/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw'                            
        else                                                                                         
            echo -n "EMACS VERSION OUT OF DATE: $curr_emacs_version. "                               
            echo 'Install a newer version.'                                                          
            emacs_path=''                                                                            
        fi                                                                                           
        export EDITOR="$emacs_path"                                                                  
        alias emacs="$emacs_path"                                                                    
    fi                                                                                               
fi
```

**`.bash_profile`**

```
source ~/.bashrc                                                                                     
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell         
session *as a function*                                                                              
LESS=-FRX;export LESS
```

Comment: Do you invoke `git` from Terminal.app or from inside Emacs (e.g. `M-x shell`)?

Comment: @lunaryorn, I invoke `git` from Terminal.app, but when I do `M-x shell` doesn't emacs source my .bashrc file? I guess I'm asking why it matters where I invoke `git`.

Comment: Which version of `git` are you using?

Comment: git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)

Comment: Try installing a non-Apple/X-code git: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301260/git-is-not-using-the-first-editor-in-my-path/13326867#13326867

Comment: :( I want to use what I got. @BertF are you saying that's the only way to get git to respect my $PATH settings?

Comment: @Avery The problem you're observing is due to a bug in Apple git.  Get `git` from macports and you'll be set!

Comment: @Avery - according to the other question/answer, it is an (undocumented) bug in Apple git, so you are stuck.  You'll need to use a different git, remove/hide the other emacs, or set EDITOR to a full path.

Comment: @Avery I can confirm the apple git (1.7.12.4) bug on OS X 10.7.5 mentioned in the comments. It works fine with git 1.9.1 from homebrew. Additionally I'd like to point to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x which contains very helpful information about setting environment variables on OS X based systems.

Answer (score 1):

> I expect to have an answer that explains WHY MacOSX doesn't pick up my
>   bashrc/profile environment changes and a solution to HOW I can get
>   MacOSX to pick up those changes.

This is not specific to OS X - here is an example:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 3.13.7-gentoo #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 24 18:40:46 CET 2014 i686 Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU 330 @ 1.60GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
$ cat .bashrc
export EDITOR="emacs"
$ echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/vim
$ mv .bashrc .bash_profile
$ logout
Connection to hostname closed.
$ ssh hostname
$ echo $EDITOR
emacs
```

For what I know and used to "live" is that environment variables are expected to reside inside `/etc/profile` (system wide) and can be extended and overwritten on a user level basis inside `~/.profile` respectively `~/.bash_profile`.

From [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as  a 
>   non-interac-    tive  shell  with the --login option, it first reads
>   and executes commands    from the file /etc/profile, if that file
>   exists.  After reading that file,    it  looks  for  ~/.bash_profile, 
>   ~/.bash_login,  and  ~/.profile, in that    order, and reads and
>   executes commands from the first one that exists  and    is readable.

On the other hand. `.bashrc` is the place to go where one places custom functions, aliases, prompt configuration, etc.

So a simple solution to your specific question - aside from using another git version in your special situation - would be to simply move your environmant variables from your `.bashrc` into a `.bash_profile`.

The Linux From Scratch project provides some pretty good [examples about how to organize the bash shell startup files](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html). Specific problems on OS X are tackled inside ["Setting environment variables in OS X?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x).

Comment: It's generally good to have something like `[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc` in `~/.bash_profile` and it's usually so by default in distributions. There's no way something in `./.bashrc` doesn't get applied to your environment.

Comment: Also your answer seems to contradict your own comment in the question of Mac OS X specificity of the issue.

Comment: Last but not least, the question wasn't about the `$EDITOR` variable but instead about the `$PATH` variable and the original poster's `.bash_profile` aparently sources the `.bashrc.`.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** set variables in `.bashrc`.  Bash only looks at this file in interactive sessions, so programs outside of an interactive session will never see any variables from `.bashrc.`

For bash, **environment variables belong into `~/.profile`**!.

To fix your problem immediately, you may set `$EDITOR` to an absolute path:

```
if [[ -e /usr/local/bin/emacs ]]; then
  export EMACS=/usr/local/bin/emacs
else
  export EMACS=emacs
```

However, the issue points to a deeper problem in your environment setup, but your question currently lacks some information (see my comment).

Generally, `$PATH` and environment variables are a mess on OS X, because there's no single place to change them (for instance, profile variables do not propagate to the desktop and GUI applications), and because OS X itself meddles with `$PATH` by means of `path_helper`.  You need to be extra careful about where you set variables, and you need use workarounds like [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) to have your environment variables available in GUI applications.

Comment: Your solution made me go and read `man bash` but I'm still not clear what goes where. It sounds like `.bashrc` gets invoked from things like emacs when doing a `M-x shell` or just firing up Terminal (since I don't login with either). What should I put in bashrc and what should I put in profile? Should I have one source the other?

Comment: I added `source ~/.bashrc` to my ~/.profile but that didn't change the behavior...

Answer (score 0):

Any program is free to set PATH inside of itself to whatever it wants -- this tactic is often used in `setuid` programs to prevent execution of the wrong (or downright bad) executables.

You'll need to find out whether Emacs **Terminal.app** creates a Bash that runs `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, both, or something else entirely. (Sorry, I'm a vim user.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
export VISUAL=emacs
```

I just tried `export VISUAL=gedit` from bash on my Ubuntu and now git uses gedit
when called from that terminal.

Comment: I'm sorry for speaking in vague terms. Indeed this attempt to answer doesn't answer the original question at all. The original poster wanted to know why `$PATH` variable doesn't get used by his instance of git (run from emacs on osx in this case) so that when `emacs` is called from git, the right version of it (using `$PATH`) is chosen.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda, OP exports $EDITOR expecting it do the right thing. $VISUAL is preffered to $EDITOR in a graphical session.

Comment: Your statement above (1) has no relation to the problem described by original poster and (2) is false. EDITOR works well for the original poster and for anyone else when VISUAL is not set. Also the meaning of VISUAL doesn't change in graphical environments in any way.